# How do I find any string Perl?

Tags: string, find, any

I am new at Perl and I've got a problem. 
I would like to find any string in this part of code:

```
my $change = $item->look_down(
  _tag=> 'td',
  class => 'colZmiana change  ' #?????
);
```

In my HTML code, there is `colZmiana change up`, `colZmiana change down` or `colZmiana change`.
I would like `class =>` find every `colZmiana change`.

Could anyone help me ?